# Unexpected token B in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at cart.page.ts:25

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

My code is working and then after I refresh I am getting an error please help!!

```
 this.storage.forEach((data) => {
      let storedProducts = {};
      let parseFromStorage = JSON.parse(data); //ERROR HERE
      console.log(data);
      this.cartData.push(parseFromStorage);
      storedProducts['product_id'] = parseFromStorage.id;
      storedProducts['price'] = parseInt(parseFromStorage.price);
      storedProducts['quantity'] = 1;
      this.baseProducts.push(storedProducts);

    }).then(() => {
      console.log('Product stored in Ionic Storage: ',this.baseProducts);
    });
```

Comment: What is `data` ? Verify it with jsonlint.com . It must be incorrect

Comment: Also, how can u put `.then` over forEach ? is this a working code

Comment: @ShashankVivek the method `forEach` of store returns a promise, that is why it is using `then` .. Anyway, I agree with you that is important to know what is in data

Comment: @cabesuon : Ok, may be its ionic stuff. I have not worked on it

Comment: @JokeZz what is the error you're getting?

Comment: data must be in json stringify format like `"{"x":5,"y":6}"` but seems it is not correct format. put `console.log(data);` before JSON.parse and share.